# How to use HTML5 semantic tags in HTML email creative?

Tags: html

I'm trying to find out if it is possible to use `HTML5` semantic tags in `HTML` email creative? Or is it still advised to stick with nested tables structure? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think going the semantic route is best as the browser or email service can pick up on tags to more easily create a calendar date, send an address to a mapping service, or call a phone number.